# Elixir: How to define multiple macros using a List as a variable?

Tags: macros, elixir

I'm trying to define two macros with the following code but it failed with `** (CompileError) iex:12: undefined function name/0`.
The function parameter `name` cannot be unquoted in the do block of `defmacro`.

What is the reason of this ?
Is there any way to solve this?

(Elixir version is 1.2.5)

```
defmodule IEx.MyHelpers do

  def default_env do
    __ENV__
  end

  [:functions, :macros] |> Enum.each(fn name ->
    defmacro unquote(name)(option \\ :all) do
      import MapSet
      quote do
        case unquote(option) do
          x when x in [:a, :all]      -> __ENV__     |> Map.take([unquote(name)])
          x when x in [:d, :default]  -> default_env |> Map.take([unquote(name)])
          x when x in [:i, :imported] ->
            difference(new(Map.take(__ENV__, [unquote(name)])),
                       new(Map.take(default_env, [unquote(name)])))
            |> MapSet.to_list
        end
      end
    end
  end)

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically need to unquote twice, since the dynamic macro generation already is an implicit macro. You should be fine with adding the following line at the top of your `defmacro`:

```
name = unquote(name)
```